# Play framework 2.0 calling a method before request is routed

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.3

I want to do some stuff with incomming requests just before they are routed to their corresponding methods. What I want to do is just the same, no matter what the actual route is. So instead of calling a method in each and every route method, there should be a way to "intercept" that request just prior.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I think requestHandlers can help you, scala: [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpRequestHandlers), java: [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaHttpRequestHandlers)

Answer (score 1):

You should use Action Composition in Play framework to do some thing before your action get invoked, See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition